# How can I display the entire web page in fullscreen and disable f11 and ESC buttons?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an online quiz with PHP, HTML and Javascript. When the user clicks the "Start Quiz" button, the page must be shown in fullscreen, and the f11 and ESC buttons must be disabled to prevent users from exiting the fullscreen mode. How can I do that?
Here is the code for the fullscreen mode:

```
var elem = document.documentElement;
                function openFullscreen() {
                if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
                    elem.requestFullscreen();
                } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
                    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
                } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
                    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
                    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
                }
            }

            function closeFullscreen() {
                if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                    document.exitFullscreen();
                } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
                } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
                    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
                } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                    document.msExitFullscreen();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I would navigate away from your quiz, and never come back, if you'd play around with _my_ browser. It's a user's option to rule their own screen, don't mess with that.

Answer (score 0):

In a regular browser setting this is usually not possible due to the security implications.

You can use things like [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) though: With electron you can create an application with "kiosk" mode, which basically does that.